# though it to be safe

Tags: conjunctions

I saw this paragraph in a TOEIC sample test.

> My brother-in-law tried his best to assemble the seat as he saw from the diagrams in the instructions and from his best judement **though it to be safe**. However, the belt buckle mechanism was very easy for my niece to open by herself, and did so on a car journey.

My question: is "though" a conjunction?

Is this phrase "though it to be safe" grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be a typo, it should read:

> and from his best jud**g**ement though**t** it to be safe.